# Trying to find a way to play dnd?

Tags: dnd-5e

My friends and I want to play D&D, but I'm in a country where it's very hard to get the D&D rule books, and because of an impending lockdown I can't get them shipped to where I am.

I've played the game a few times and have followed a few campaigns on Twitch/YouTube so I'm familiar with the basic rules. But, I want to know if anyone here has any advice as to how I would get a game started up.

(Note that Internet access is fairly limited and wizards.com is also completely unavailable to me.)

Preferably, I'd like to play D&D 5e. If there's an easier one I would be open to suggestions

Comment: And welcome to our stack! Please take our [tour] and you can also visit the [help] for more information.

Comment: Do you have access to DriveThruRPG or DMsGuild?

Comment: Are you comfortable adding country-specific information? I'm wondering if there is a more specific answer based on your local situation. For example, specific import or quarantine requirements, availability in your local language(s), etc.

Comment: Fellow users in your country may be able to help, but they can't help without knowing your country. (There's a field to enter your location on the user profile page.)

Comment: i dont want to say where i am, but ive looked around over here and havent found much. theres one store about an hour away from where im located that has some stuff. the lockdown rules are interesting, the government is putting the whole country on a lockdown starting this week, meaning no traveling more than 500 meters from your home and only essential stores are allowed to be open. and even if they didnt make a lockdown, the school that im in has extremely strict rules. im not allowed outside of a 3 block radius, let alone an hour trip outside of the city lol

Comment: also saying which country im in doesnt help because i speak english. im not even fluent in the local language lol

Comment: Have you tried adding in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat)?

Comment: Do you know why WotC and other websites don't work for you? If this question turns into whack-a-mole to find websites which work through some mysterious website filter or arcane browser(?) it probably isn't something we can entertain.

Comment: Actually re-reading it; what are you trying to ask for? I think it was interpreted as "How do I find the starting materials I need?" which see above for whack-a-mole problem. But are you trying to ask for how to start a campaign with someone (presumably new players)? Or are you trying to find rpg's which are freely available and which you can access? I'd really like clarity in this, because worst case this is both whack-a-mole and shopping (neither work with how the site is built).

Comment: But if you are trying to figure out how to access official D&D 5e materials, I think we need more information as to what is preventing you from accessing these sites. It is unclear what the rules are that are blocking sites.

Comment: I want to know of resources that i could potentially use online to be able to dm (which is hard because of my internet) as well as which campaigns would be good to do with beginners. My question was really just for general advice on how it could practically start, i didnt really have anything specific in mind i just wanted general/practical ideas to get a game going. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Just got access to dmsguild

Comment: Theres a very strong filter on the computer i have access to and it blocks most things (to be honest its shocking that i can even get to this site). But if i download a pdf on a diff computer or a smartphone then i can probably email myself that pdf. Maybe that would work

Comment: If you'd like this reopened, please try and focus on one issue that we can help you with.

Comment: My advise to you is, with your several different questions of: 1) Accessible resources to use online, 2) Good campaigns for beginners and 3) How to get a game started - You can split these into three separate questions to post.  As opposed to putting them in only one post, which can then get closed for being too broad. As @NautArch said, one question needs to be on one focus. But, if you put them separately, that way you should be able to get answers for all you want to know!

Comment: And don't forget to search the site first for existing answers!